# Remove logs from Flutter application using ProGuard

Tags: android, flutter, proguard, dexguard, appsweep

I have an Android apk created from a Flutter project. I have added this apk to AppSweep and it returns the following issue: **The app logs information**.

To solve this, I have added the following configuration in ProGuard. The number of findings has been reduced, but I didn't manage to totally solve the issue.

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

I have also attached an image with the issue returned by AppSweep: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqTrB.png

Answer (score 0):

Logging removal is part of ProGuard's optimizations.

If optimization is disabled for the code that includes the logging statements, it will not be removed.

Double check if your configuration has any `keep,includecode` options that target this code and whether keeping the code is required.